# How to display relational data in a React/Redux project?

Tags: reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, react-redux, redux-saga

I have joined a project recently and I have to add some new features. But it's quite challenging when it's not your code. So the new feature is to display the name of a common friend or common friends. For now it only displaying the number of common friends via a variable `common_friends_count`.

The /friendships/ api is only returning the number, not a object.

```
{
  "uuid": "09f0e78d-774d-4e72-bd06-5f99ccd549f1",
  "user_uuid": "12370118-bc09-41a5-b9c1-75fe802fcc6d",
  "full_name": "John Doe",
  "picture_url": "https://ucarecdn.com/945fa78c-de6a-4caf-9b3f-9638ed2bb69b/",
  "friends_count": 2,
  "common_friends_count": 1
}
```

My question is : How can I return the name(s) via the `common_friends_count` number ? Any help is appreciated.

The project is created with redux saga but as far as i can see, there's nothing about the friendship that is connected to the redux store.

Thank you ! Let me know if you need more details :)

Comment: Your question is very general and you seem to be confusing the frontend with the backend. Your data needs to be pulled from the backend via SQL, and returned to the frontend, where it will be presented. Show how your backend "model" looks like and perhaps some code.

Comment: It depends of your API. If it has an ability to provide you friends list by `user_uuid` you send send a request based on `user_uuid`.

Comment: @lazy.lizard I think I'm on the right track by using a hook that i just find in the project called "useFriends" that will fetch the friends list by the 'userId'. So maybe with something like if my friends uuid(s) are equal to the other person friends uuid(s) then fetch the common profile(s) and display their name ?

Comment: @i.brod I can see how my question seems very general, there was really too much code to paste for a better understanding on how everything worked. But I think i'm on the right tract. See above answer :)